# Render time increasing with time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Given this code

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

i = 0
k = 1

while True:
    canvas.create_text(100, 0+i, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")
    canvas.update()
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, canvas["width"], canvas["height"], fill=canvas["background"])
    canvas.after(3)
    i = i + k

    if i==-1 or i==265:
        k = -k
```

we can see that with each cycle of while loop the movement of the text slows down.

Now, since we are re-rendering the whole canvas multiple times a second, no wonder that it is slow. However, why is it slowing down with time? Is it due to the great amount of objects text and rectangle objects piling up? Can this be avoided?

Comment: Are you asking in general or in context of your example? It's a littlebit unclear, because in first place you state that there's a "no wonder" about. And after that you're got confused in the next sentence. Long story short: yes, it hit perfomance because of redrawning of an increasing amount of objects. And yes, it's avoidable.

Comment: I wanted to ask if my suspicion was correct and how can this be avoided in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of moving the text, at each iteration you create a new text item and a rectangle to hide the previous one, so the canvas gets crowded and the program slows down.

There are several ways to avoid that:

1) Delete the text instead of hiding it behind a rectangle:

```
   text = canvas.create_text(100, i, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")
   ...
   canvas.delete(text)
```

2) Change the coordinates of the existing item with `coords`:

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

i = 0
k = 1
text = canvas.create_text(100, i, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")

while True:
    canvas.coords(text, 100, i)  # change coordinates of the text
    canvas.update()
    canvas.after(3)
    i = i + k
    if i==-1 or i==265:
        k = -k
```

3) Move the existing item with `move`:

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

i = 0
k = 1
text = canvas.create_text(100, i, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")

while True:
    canvas.move(text, 0, k)  # increment by k the y coordinate of the text
    canvas.update()
    canvas.after(3)
    i = i + k
    if i==-1 or i==265:
        k = -k
```

Finally, instead of a while loop, you can also use the `after` method to make the animation. Something like:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

def motion(i, k):
    canvas.coords(text, 100, i)
    i = i + k
    if i==-1 or i==265:
        k = -k
    canvas.after(3, motion, i, k)

i = 0
k = 1
text = canvas.create_text(100, 0, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")

motion(i, k)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was actually wondering how to avoid the `while` loop as well. You're a true mind reader :D

Answer (score 1):

### Trivia

Your suspicion was correct. Redraw/Render time increases because you leak memory by stacking objects (they're don't disappear on each iteration, they're kept in memory) and because `tkinter` redraws them all at the same time. From that point I think that the solution is clear.

### Answer

Sure it can be avoided.

There's two options:

1. If all you need is just to animate one object - you can simply move one (and redraw one) object at the time.

Consider this example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas()
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.canvas["width"], self.canvas["height"], fill=self.canvas["background"])
        self.text = self.canvas.create_text(100, 1, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")
        self.step = 3
        self.simulate_things()

    def simulate_things(self):
        if 0 <= self.canvas.coords(self.text)[1] + self.step <= self.canvas.winfo_height():
            # no need to change direction - still inside canvas
            pass
        else:
            # switch direction
            self.step *= -1
        
        # you can use coords method as alternative
        self.canvas.move(self.text, 0, self.step)

        # scheduling next move
        self.after(41, self.simulate_things)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

2. If there's any idea behind of multiple objects - you can switch their `state` to `hidden`/`disabled` (it's also more optimal way than deleting of the object, because we reduce `id`/`item` managing to a minimum). That option will tell `tkinter` not to redraw them.
   However, you need to track objects, which are already created to prevent a memory leak!

Consider this example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas()
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.canvas["width"], self.canvas["height"], fill=self.canvas["background"])
        self.texts = {}
        self.i = 1
        self.step = 3
        self.simulate_things()

    def simulate_things(self):
        if self.i in self.texts:
            # hide previous object (if exists)
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.texts[self.i], state='hidden')

        if 0 <= self.i + self.step <= self.canvas.winfo_height():
            # no need to change direction - still inside canvas
            pass
        else:
            # switch direction
            self.step *= -1
        
        self.i += self.step
        
        if self.i in self.texts:
            # show hidden object for a step (if exists)
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.texts[self.i], state='normal')
        else:
            # or create a new one
            self.texts[self.i] = self.canvas.create_text(100, self.i, text="Python 3.6!", fill="red")

        # scheduling next move
        self.after(41, self.simulate_things)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

As you can see - your main goal in managing perfomance is to decrease the amount of redrawings (and to keep the amount of objects at minimum).

### Links

- [Canvas
  widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html)
- [Methods on Canvas widgets](http://infohost.nmt.edu/%7Eshipman/soft/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html)
- [Tk Canvas documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm)
- [Tk Perfomance](http://wiki.tcl.tk/393)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!